# What happened to the esprima-six npm module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

My npm project has the esprima-six npm module as a transitive dependency. Recently, it has become impossible to download, as seen in the following output from `npm install`:

```
npm ERR! 404 Not Found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'esprima-six' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'syntax-error'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.
```

On the npm site, esprima-six cannot be found:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/esprima-six

But Google's cache for the page shows that it used to exist: [http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:81uuMFHrDeMJ:https://www.npmjs.com/package/esprima-six+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=ubuntu](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:81uuMFHrDeMJ:https://www.npmjs.com/package/esprima-six%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=ubuntu)

So why did the module become unavailable? And what is the best way to get my project building again?

Edit: in the end I updated the dependency which depended on esprima-six to a later version which didn't need it.

Comment: My advice to you would be to, if possible, use an alternative module with similar functionality *as early as possible* - it will save you a lot of trouble down the line

Comment: [This project](https://github.com/jquery/esprima) seems to be active, so it'll probably be up again soon. Since it has no dependencies, you could potentially just get the [src folder](https://github.com/jquery/esprima/tree/master/src) and include it in your project. It's written in typescript, though, so you'll have to compile that, i guess?

Comment: There is no esprima-six any more. However, plain [esprima](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esprima) seems to be the same project.

Comment: Your google cache link doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`esprima-six`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esprima-six) has been [unpushlished](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/unpublish) and is no more.

It's hard to track down what exactly has happened, but it seems that `esprima-six` was a module based on the *unofficial* [`harmony` branch](https://github.com/jquery/esprima/tree/harmony) of the project that has been discountinoud in May 2015, [following](https://github.com/jquery/esprima/issues/1172) the [deprecation of `esprima-fb`](https://github.com/facebook/esprima/issues/111) (a fork that added JSX syntax).

And now `esprima-six` is no longer needed, as [Esprima 2.0 officially supports ES6](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2015/02/towards-ecmascript-6-with-esprima-2.html).

> What is the best way to get my project building again?

The [stance of Ariya Hidayat](https://github.com/thlorenz/redeyed/pull/4#issuecomment-153238131), Esprima's maintainer, is that you should just **switch to Esprima 2.x**.

> My project has the `esprima-six` npm module as a *transitive* dependency.

In that case, it's probably enough to update your direct dependency, they will have switched already.